# Sorting array java

Tags: java

Hello guys I have a problem in my program. I have to call the class and write or not number in the main parameter to tell how much numbers will be printed and they have to be the biggest one's. The problem is that when I print few random numbers if they are equal or some negatives they only show up one time and sometimes they are not the biggest ones. if it is not clear I'll post the code and an example .

```
for(a = 0; a < array.length; a++){ 
    for(b = 0; b < array.length-1; b++){
        if(array[b] > array[b+1]){
            aux = array[b];
            array[b] = array[b+1];
            array[b+1] = aux;
        }
```

I used this code to sort them but i dont know if its alright.
ps: i cant use sort methods or objects just simple logic.

Comment: why don't you implement some sorting algorithm? like Mergesort or Quicksort?

Comment: i cant use bubblesort and other stuff just loops

Comment: consequently, you are using bubble sort http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort  just not implemented quite right

Comment: There are at least half a dozen sorting algorithms out there, are you sure you are not allowed to use any? Try to understand how they work and then you can implement them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have left out a few brackets here and there.

First of all your compare `if(array[b] > array[b+1])` will sort lowest to highest. If you want it highest to lowers then you will want to change to `if(array[b] < array[b+1]`

Here is the code that will sort an array from highest to lowers.

`for(int a = 0; a < array.length; a++){ 
            for(int b = 0; b < array.length-1; b++){
                if(array[b] < array[b+1]){
                    aux = array[b];
                    array[b] = array[b+1];
                    array[b+1] = aux;
                }
            }
        }`

This is bubble sort by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what your code is doing by walking through it.

The problem is that you should have if(array[b] < array[b+1]) if you want to sort from highest to lowest.  array[b] > array[b+1] does the opposite, lowest to highest.

Your current code does this:

Say I have an array of numbers: 1, 2, 3, 5

First Inner Loop:

```
b = 0 and array.length = 4
array[b] = 1 and array[b+1] = 2
1 is less than 2, so nothing changes
```

Second Inner Loop:

```
b = 1 and array.length = 4
array[b] = 2 and array[b+1] = 3
2 is less than 3, so nothing changes
```

Third Inner Loop:

```
b = 2 and array.length = 4
array[b] = 3 and array[b+1] = 5
3 is less than 5 so nothing changes
```

And so on.   This should make it obvious that the sort is going the wrong way, and your sign needs to change.

Now, to implement this properly as a bubble sort, you should also not bother sorting the last element looked at in each iteration.  A proper bubble sort would look something like:

```
 for (int a = 0; a < thisArray.length(); a++){
      for (int b = 0; b < (thisArray.length() - a - 1); b++{
           if (thisArray[b] < thisArray[b+1]){
               holder = thisArray[b+1];
               thisArray[b+1] = thisArray[b];
               thisArray[b] = holder;
           }
      }
 }
```

Read the bubble sort wiki page if you are curious how this is better than what you are doing.  The gist of it is that the largest number will always be moved to the back, so we don't need to keep looking at it to make sure it is the largest number.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort